# Pass selected UIImage image anto another view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to pass selected `UIImage` into another `viewController`without using `segue`.

I have `UICollectionViewCell` ,so when I click on particular cell, selected image will show on another `viewController`.

Comment: Use delegates to do it!

Comment: can you help me with code?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try This without segue,

Create  `@property(nonatomic,strong) UIImage *diplayImage;` in another viewController.h file

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NewController * viewcontroller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newController"];

    viewcontroller.diplayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage.png"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: or, if you are not using NavigationController, just use `func present(UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` on `self`

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates to send data between classes:

First create a delegate:

```
@protocol ImageSelectDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)selectedImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end
```

and  implement this protocol in the class you want to send your image :

```
@interface CollectionDetailViewController()< ImageSelectDelegate >
```

and in the collection controller, create a property for the delegate :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id< ImageSelectDelegate > imageSelectDelegate;
```

and in the didSelect method, just do:

```
[self.imageSelectDelegate selectedImage:imageTosend];
```

In the other class, you can obtain the image in this method:

```
-(void) selectedImage:(UIImage *)image{
    self.image = image;

}
```

Make sure your imageSelectDelegate is not nil, else this won't work